# Image changing size and position when put in an a tag

Tags: css, image, flexbox, href, image-size

I want this image to be a link.
But when I put the img tag in an a tag, the image suddenly changes position and size and I don't understand why. It seems like the whole container gets smaller.

Here's the [desired look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1EsO.jpg)

And here's what [happens when the a tag is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acQj4.jpg)

Edit: I came a little closer to understanding what the problem is, but still haven't figured out the solution. The anchor tag is bigger than the image it holds. Så there's a big area around the image that is clickable and takes up space. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Edit2: When I set the image's width in px instead of %, the problem seems to be solved, but don't know why.

Code without img in < a > tag:

```
<div class="container-background-grey portfolio-presentation-container">
  <p class="portfolio-presentation-text1">
    <a class="longer-text-link" href="index.html"
      >Logo-design, illustrationer och tryckt material för småskalig
      producent av hundhalsband och koppel.</a
    >
  </p>

  <img
    class="portfolio-presentation-image1"
    src="../Images/Linnelur/poster.jpeg"
    alt="Linnelur-poster."
  />
</div>
```

Code with the img inside the < a > tag:

```
<div class="container-background-grey portfolio-presentation-container">
  <p class="portfolio-presentation-text1">
    <a class="longer-text-link" href="index.html"
      >Logo-design, illustrationer och tryckt material för småskalig
      producent av hundhalsband och koppel.</a
    >
  </p>

  <a href="index.html">
    <img
      class="portfolio-presentation-image1"
      src="../Images/Linnelur/poster.jpeg"
      alt="Linnelur-poster."
    />
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.portfolio-presentation-container {
          /* FLEXBOX: */
          display: flex;
          justify-content: flex-start;
          align-items: center;
          gap: 20%;
        }

.portfolio-presentation-text1 {
  max-width: 50%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-weight: 400;

  flex: 1 1 50%;
}

.longer-text-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15pt;
}

.portfolio-presentation-image1 {
  /* background-color: darkgoldenrod; */
  max-width: 20%;
  padding: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Simply put them the two (text and img) in different `<div>`  and apply `justify-content:center` in parent `<div>`

Comment: The problem remains unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve!

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #bbdefb;
  padding: 15px;
  gap: 5px;
}

.text-container {
  flex: 0.3;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.image-conatiner {
  text-align: right;
  flex: 0.8;
}

.image-conatiner img {
  height: 300px;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="text-container">
    <a class="link" href="index.html">Logo-design, illustrationer och tryckt material för småskalig
          producent av hundhalsband och koppel.</a>
  </div>

  <div class="image-conatiner">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img class="portfolio-presentation-image1" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51p6Vj65vxS._SX301_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg" alt="Linnelur-poster." /></a>
  </div>
```